# How to read data from a text file and store it in a QVector for plotting with QCustomPlot?

Tags: qt, vector, plot, readfile

For learning purposes, I would like to plot data stored in a text file using QCustomPlot within Qt. The QCustomPlot takes a QVector (double), and when I create the vector by hand (initializing the vector with values), the plotting works. But when I read in the values from the text file, nothing happens. I get no compiler errors and there is no plotting.

I used the code snippets from [code example](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/support/forum/450). You can see the code I am using below. I spent a few hours reading through the web, but it was to no avail.

```
    QVector<double> v;
    QVector<double> x(20), y(20);
    QFile textFile("Data3.txt");
    if(textFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        double d;
        QTextStream textStream(&textFile);
        while (!textStream.atEnd()) {
            textStream >> d;
            if(textStream.status() == QTextStream::Ok){
                v.append(d);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<=20; ++i)
        {
            x[i] = i;
            y[i] = v[i];
        }

}

    QVector<double>   myVectorx({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19});
    QVector<double> myVectory({0.5,1,3,5,7,10});
    ui->custom2Widget->addGraph();

    ui->custom2Widget->graph()->setData(myVectorx, y);
    //ui->custom2Widget->graph()->addData(x,y);
    ui->custom2Widget->graph()->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));
    ui->custom2Widget->xAxis->setRange(0,25);
    ui->custom2Widget->yAxis->setRange(0, 100);
    ui->custom2Widget->xAxis->setLabel("Time");
    ui->custom2Widget->yAxis->setLabel("CO2 values");
    ui->custom2Widget->replot();
```

The data file looks like this (it is one column, not one after the other in the same row):

315.71
317.45
317.5
317.1
315.86
314.93
313.2
312.66
313.33

Comment: In the provided example, the setRanges are false. They are too low for the data. In my application, I had broader values for the x and y axis.

Comment: First of all, in you `for` loop where you're filling `x` and `y` vectors, you are getting out of their range. These can have 20 elements, so you can access `[0;20]` indices, meanwhile your loop goes to `<=20`.